# Equivalence between measured foliations and laminations on surfaces

Tags: surfaces, low-dimensional-topology, foliations

A well known theorem of Thurston asserts the existence of a homeomorphism between the spaces of measured foliations and of measured laminations of any hyperbolic surface. Where can I find a construction of this homeomorphism?

I am aware that the epilogue of Penner-Harer "Combinatorics of Train Tracks" mentions that a measured train track $(\tau,\mu)$ gives rise to both a measured foliation and to a measured lamination, however it seems to me that this is not enough for the definition of a homeomorphism since for example such $(\tau,\mu)$ is not unique for a given measured foliation or lamination. Also, one needs to be careful about Whitehead equivalence.

Answer (score 0):

A web search produced [this account](https://home.iiserb.ac.in/~kashyap/project.pdf) of that theorem, written up by Kashyap Rajeevsarathy.

Comment: I noticed that link as well, but it is dead and I was unable to find his paper online.

Comment: It's not dead for me, I click on it and up pops the paper.

Comment: That is very mysterious -- I tried and failed on 4 different browsers on my laptop and on my phone. I see only the google cached version without formulas nor pictures.  If it is okay with you I will email you and perhaps you could forward it to me.

Comment: I got the paper from Lee. (Also, in the meantime, Rajeevsarathy's paper appeared back online). It is not really a proof but a rough discussion of the equivalence, following Penner-Harer. For example, it considers only foliations with all leaves compact and with no leaves compact, missing the mixed case. More importantly, it does not address the issues with Penner-Harer's discussion which I raised in my question.